# Confusion in understanding the theorem on Amortization

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I was reading a book on Algorithm Analysis by Micheal T Goodrich. I came across amortization technique and I got struck in understanding the proof of theorem. I am putting the theorem and the proof and the part that I need some more explanation. Please help me:

**Theorem:** A series of *n* operations on an initially **empty** clearable table implemented with an array takes O(n) time

Definition of clearable table: This Abstract data type stores table of elements, which can be accessed by their index in the table. In addition this ADT supports the following two methods:

> add(e): Add the element *e* to the next available cell in the table.
>   clear : Empty the table by removing all its elements.

**Proof**: Let M<sub>0</sub>....,M<sub>n-1</sub> be the series of operations performed on S, and let M<sub>i0</sub>,....,M<sub>ik-1</sub> be the clear operations within the series. We then have,

> 0<= i<sub>0</sub> < .... < i <sub>k-1</sub> <= n-1.
>
> Let us also define i<sub>-1</sub> = -1. The running time of operation M<sub>i<sub>j</sub></sub> (a clear operation) is O(i<sub>j</sub> - i<sub>j-1</sub>), because at most i<sub>j</sub> - i<sub>j-1</sub> -1 elements could have been added into the table (using the add operation) since the previous clear operation M<sub>i<sub>j-1</sub></sub> or since the beginning of the series.

Question:

1. Why and how i<sub>-1</sub> = -1 is defined?
2. I did not understand "because at most i<sub>j</sub> - i<sub>j-1</sub> -1 elements could have been added into the table (using the add operation) since the previous clear operation M<sub>i<sub>j-1</sub></sub> or since the beginning of the series". Please explain me more on this statement on why **-1** came into the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with your second question. That `-1` comes from the fact, that both i<sub>j</sub> and i<sub>j-1</sub> are clear operations, you want to count only the add operations in between, so you do not have to count the left and right values. (For example there are 3 values between 3 and 7: 4, 5, 6.)

The answer for your first question: because it is before the first element and it works well with the quoted text. (For example assume the first clear is at index `2`; between i<sub>-1</sub>=-1 and i<sub>0</sub>=2, there are `2` integers: 0 and 1, so the formula of i<sub>j</sub>-i<sub>j-1</sub>-1 = 2-(-1)-1=2 still works well.) You could use a smaller number as well, but that would be more confusing.

Comment: Very helpful. I got the exact answer I was looking for.